# Upload file using windows Explorer

Tags: java

I need a way to open windows file explorer to upload file to a desktop application. 
what i'm trying to do is press upload button then  windows explorer pop-up and then i select a file to upload it into the database
**so what i'm asking is** how to open windows explorer to do it. i cant find any reference to this in java SE. 
if you know at-least have any reference, that should be enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need  is a jFileChooser:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the below snippet to implement what you're looking for,

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    //This is where a real application would open the file.
    System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getName());
} else {
    System.out.println("Open command cancelled by user.");
}
```